# Inserting Large excel's into MongoDB with Node.js and async.queue

Tags: javascript, excel, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to upload and insert large excel  files (100K's of rows; 10-100M+) into mongo.

```
    var cv_json = require('convert-json');
    cv_json({
    // now supporting csv, xls, xlsx, xml format
      input: '/home/local/ASSYST-COC/sobharani/SMMC/DART - Sample Data File.xls',
      output: null
    }, function (err, result) {
     if (err) {
     console.error(err);
    } else {
    console.log(result);
    }

 });
```

This is working only small amount of data .how to use async.queue.

I tried this approach. But it's taking more time to load 4L data (around 1 
 hour).But I need to load more than 4L+ data.I want this data to be store in seconds or 5 to 10 min.

```
    var cv_json = require('convert-json');
    var async = require('async');

   var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; //require mongodb 

   MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/ee', function (err, db) { 

if (err) throw err;

var collection = db.collection('csvdata');

var queue = async.queue(collection.insert.bind(collection), 200);

console.time("queryTime"); //time start

cv_json({
    // now supporting csv, xls, xlsx, xml format
    input: '/home/local/ASSYST-COC/sobharani/Desktop/JSONto.csv',
    output: null
}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {


        queue.push(result, function (err, res) {

            if (err) throw err;

        });
    }

});

queue.drain = function () {
    console.log('all items have been processed');
    console.timeEnd("queryTime"); //end time    
    db.close();
}

console.timeEnd("queryTime"); //end time
```

});

Comment: What happens when processing larger files?

Comment: Could you add system profiling data? It's hard to guess where you might be experiencing delays. You may have expectations that cannot be met.

Comment: can you share a file that takes an hour to process?

Answer (score 0):

Every insert is going to generate a synchronous call to the database.
Mongo locks the table for each insert, which slows even more the process.

I'd recommend to batch insert (many documents inserted at once) by providing an array of documents to the `collection.insert` method.

Cf. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#db.collection.insert

Answer (score 0):

You should use mongo batch insert. Batch insert support no more than 1000 write operations so you will need to use a bulk. This is an example (in coffeescript)

```
    #Mongo cannot do more than 1000 batch insert, bulk will divide it
      bulk = yourModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
      for data in veryBigArray
        bulk.insert data

      bulk.execute (err) ->
        if err? then console.log(err) else
          console.log "INSERTING %s DATA IN MONGO", veryBigArray.length
```

Answer (score -1):

The first step is to determine whether the time is being consumed by the conversion to json or the load into MongoDB. So try commenting out the step that inserts the result into MongoDB and see whether it still takes a long time just to do the conversion.